# error Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel_loader'

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I keep getting the error `Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'babel_loader'` Why? babel-loader is installed in node/modules, `@babel-core` too, both are also present in `package.json`. I've tried to reinstall babel-loader, changed webpack.config several times, and restarted both IDE and terminal, and it still doesn't work.

My `webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "main.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"),
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    static: {
        directory: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    },
    port: 3000,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(js)$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel_loader'
            },
        },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node-modules'],
    extensions: ['*', '.js'],
  }
};
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "mybuh",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack serve --mode development",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.5",
    "webpack": "^5.83.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be 'babel-loader' instead of 'babel_loader'?

Comment: Thank you! How could i not notice this typo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was, i made a typo, i wrote

```
{
    "loader": "babel_loader"
}
```

instead of:

```
{
    "loader": "babel-loader"
}
```